# nginx force rewrite of full address

Tags: nginx, rewrite

On my enterprise intranet, websites can be accessed in two ways. With their alias, like `https://foo` or with their full address, something like `https://foo.example.internal`.

I want to configure my nginx server to force user to use the second option. So if they browse `https://foo`, I want the nginx server to rewrite the address to `https://foo.example.internal`.

I've tried several options:

```
http {
  server {
    server_name foo;

    # Test 1
    rewrite ^https://foo/(.*)$ https://foo.example.internal/$1;

    # Test 2
    rewrite ^/foo/(.*)$ https://foo.example.internal/$1;

    # Test 3
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://foo.example.internal/$1;
  }
}
```

`Test1` and `Test2` has no effect (i.e. the user may access the website on `https://foo` or `https://foo.example.internal`), while `Test3` does the rewrite from `https://foo` to `https://foo.example.internal` but the latest does not work (nothing is returned by the nginx server, I suspect that there is some loop in that URL rewrite).

So, how can I force nginx to rewrite `https://foo` to `https://foo.example.internal`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the problem.
The working solution is done by setting 2 servers:

```
http {

  server {
    server_name foo;
    listen 443 ssl;

    return 301 https://foo.example.internal$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    server_name foo.example.internal;
    listen 443 ssl;

    # rest of configuration
  }


}
```